# Kotlin's Generics: Type mismatch in generic map parameter

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following code that uses generics:

```
abstract class Event(val name: String)

interface ValueConverter<E : Event> {

    fun convert(event: E): Float

    fun getEventClass(): Class<E>

}

class ValueConverters {

    private val converters = HashMap<String, ValueConverter<Event>>()

    fun <E : Event> register(converter: ValueConverter<E>) {
        converters.put(converter.getEventClass().name, converter)
    }

    fun unregister(eventClass: Class<Event>) {
        converters.remove(eventClass.name)
    }

    fun <E : Event> convert(event: E): Float {
        return converters[event.javaClass.name]?.convert(event) ?: 0.0f
    }

    fun clear() {
        converters.clear()
    }

}
```

But on this line:

```
converters.put(converter.getEventClass().name, converter)
```

it gives an error:

> Type mismatch. Expected ValueConverter<Event>. Found ValueConverter<E>.

I also tried something like this:

```
class ValueConverters {

    private val converters = HashMap<String, ValueConverter<Event>>()

    fun register(converter: ValueConverter<Event>) {
        converters.put(converter.getEventClass().name, converter)
    }

    fun unregister(eventClass: Class<Event>) {
        converters.remove(eventClass.name)
    }

    fun convert(event: Event): Float {
        return converters[event.javaClass.name]?.convert(event) ?: 0.0f
    }

    fun clear() {
        converters.clear()
    }

}
```

But the problem is when calling `ValueConverters.register()` with something like:

```
class SampleEvent1 : Event(name = SampleEvent1::class.java.name)

class SampleValueConverter1 : ValueConverter<SampleEvent1> {

    override fun convert(event: SampleEvent1): Float = 0.2f

    override fun getEventClass(): Class<SampleEvent1> = SampleEvent1::class.java

}

converters.register(converter = SampleValueConverter1())
```

It also gives the similar Type mismatch error.

How should I declare the generics so that I could use any class that implements ValueConverter and accepts any class that extends Event?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is on this line:

`private val converters = HashMap<String, ValueConverter<Event>>()`

The values of this map are limited to `ValueConverter<Event>`. So if you have a class

`class FooEvent : Event`

and a value converter:

`ValueConverter<FooEvent>`,

you couldn't store that value converter in your map. What you would actually want is a `*` star projection type.

`private val converters = HashMap<String, ValueConverter<*>>()`

Now you can put whatever value converter in the map.

---

However, this uncovers another problem: How does

`fun <E : Event> convert(event: E): Float`

know what the generic type of the returned converter in the map is? After all, the map might contain multiple converters for different event types!

IntelliJ promptly complains:

[image: Out-projected type 'ValueConverter<*>?' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun convert(event: E): Float defined in ValueConverter'.]

But you already know the generic type because your map key is the name of the generic type parameter!

So simply cast the returned value by the map with force:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <E : Event> convert(event: E): Float {
    val converter = converters[event.javaClass.name] ?: return 0.0f
    return (converter as ValueConverter<E>).convert(event)
}
```

---

If you are curious why the compiler did not complain about your converter function earlier: Remember how your map could only hold `ValueConverter<Event>` and only that class? This means that the compiler knew you could pass any subclass of `Event` into this converter. Once you changed to a star projection type, the compiler doesn't know if this might be a `ValueConverter<FooEvent>`, or a `ValueConverter<BazEvent>`, etc. - making the effective function signature of a given converter in your map `convert(event: Nothing)`:
[image]
because nothing is a valid input.